# Is there a way to delete certain elements in a linked list above a certain number?

Tags: java, function, linked-list

I have a linked list and I am trying to make a function that removes charms above a certain price. Lets say I have 4 charms and two of them cost $1.25 how would I remove them?

I got my function to traverse the Linked list and remove the charms above the price but I get an error saying it cannot set the node because it is null

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        CharmList Bracelet = new CharmList();
        
        Bracelet.add(new Charm("YOLO", 1.25));
        Bracelet.add(new Charm("Donald Duck", 1.25));
        Bracelet.add(new Charm("Hello Kitty", 3.25));
        Bracelet.add(new Charm("Drums", 4.25));

        System.out.print(Bracelet);
        System.out.println(Bracelet.total());
    System.out.println(Bracelet.findPrice("YOLO"));

    Bracelet.remove(1.25);
    System.out.println(Bracelet);
    
                
  }
}
```

```
void remove(double price) {
        try {
            CharmNode back = null;
            CharmNode current = list;
            boolean found = false;
            
            while (current != null && !found) {
                if(current.getCharm().getPrice() == price) {
                    found = true;
                } else {
                    back = current;
                    current = current.getNextNode();
                }
                
                if (found) {
                    back.setNode(current.getNextNode());
                    current.setNode(null);
                }
            }
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
```

```
public class CharmList {

    private CharmNode list;
    
    CharmList(){
        list = null;
    }
    
    void add(Charm c) {
        try {
            CharmNode temp = new CharmNode(c);
            CharmNode current = list;
            CharmNode back = null;
            boolean found = false;


            while((current != null) && (!found)) {
                if(temp.getCharm().getName().compareTo(current.getCharm().getName())<0) {
                    found = true;
                } else {
                    back = current;
                    current = current.getNextNode();

                }
            }
                temp.setNode(current);
                
                if(back == null) {

                    list = temp;
                }else {
                    back.setNode(temp);
                }
            
                
                
            } catch(NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
    void remove(double price) {
        try {
            CharmNode back = null;
            CharmNode current = list;
            boolean found = false;
            
            while (current != null && !found) {
                if(current.getCharm().getPrice() == price) {
                    found = true;
                } else {
                    back = current;
                    current = current.getNextNode();
                }
                
                if (found) {
                    back.setNode(current.getNextNode());
                    current.setNode(null);
                }
            }
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    } 
    
  public double findPrice(String name) {
    try {
      CharmNode back = null;
      CharmNode current = list;
      boolean found = false;

      while (current != null && !found) {
        if (current.getCharm().getName().compareToIgnoreCase(name) == 0) {
          found = true;
        } else {
          back = current;
          current = current.getNextNode();
        }

        if (found) {
           return current.getCharm().getPrice();
        }
      }
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0.0;
  }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        
        CharmNode current = list;
        
        while(current != null) {
            result += current.getCharm().getName() + ", ";
            current = current.next;
        }
        if (list == null) {
            System.out.println("<No Charms>");
        }
        return result;
    }

  public double total() {
    double cost = 0.0;
    
        CharmNode current = list;
        
        while(current != null) {
            cost += current.getCharm().getPrice();
            current = current.next;
        }
        return cost;
  }
}
```

```
  public class CharmNode {
    
    Charm charm;
    CharmNode next;
    
    CharmNode(Charm c){
        charm = c;
        next = null;
    }
    
    public Charm getCharm(){
        return charm;
    }
    
    public CharmNode getNextNode() {
        return next;
    }
    
    void setNode(CharmNode c) {
        next = c;
    }
  
  
  
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code for `class CharmList` and `class CharmNode`.  I suspect you are not using `java.util.LinkedList<E>`, but using your own Linked List.  Either way, we should see the code.

Comment: I added both CharmList and CharmNode classes

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the first node is the one you are trying to remove, which means `back` is `null` hence the `NullPointerException`. You need to account for this with a special condition. So if the node to be removed is the first node then the next node needs to become the new first node:

```java
void remove(double price) {
    CharmNode prev = null;
    CharmNode current = list; // list is the first node (I would rename it)

    while (current != null) {
        // found first instance
        if (current.getCharm().getPrice() == price) {
            // current is the first
            if (prev == null) {
                list = current.getNextNode()) // set the new first node
                current.setNode(null)
            } else {
                back.setNode(current.getNextNode());
                current.setNode(null);
            }
            break;
        }
        back = current;
        current = current.getNextNode();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a few questions about the code. First of all, is the Bracelet variable the list itself? and how exactly do I set the first node?

Comment: the braclet variable is what i copied from your code and is what represents the list. I just looked at your updated code and the list variable in your linked list is ur first node So i have adapted my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The first CharmNode price matches 1.25, so it calls `back.setNode()` while `back` is `null`.

Comment: could you elaborate further?